# QT: UIC command line tool and the -tr parameter

Tags: qt

When *.ui files are saved, they generate an *.h file which defines and implements a translation method "retranslateui()" which uses a QApplication::translate call where the context for the translation equals the UI class name.

I need to be able to override that and put in my own custom context name.

The reason if you must know is that we have a non-QT legacy translation tables, with 14 languages. I built a tool that translates those strings into a *.TS file. The problem is, there IS NO CONTEXT, it's just a flat list of strings, so my tool forces one context for my entire application. The automatic generation of translate method calls where the context = the UI class name fails my ui translation.

I found that the UIC command line utility, creating this *.h file from the *.ui file has a parameter to define a different translation method. I can use this to route to my own translation method that'll add on the single context. My problem is that I can't find out how to change the UIC call from qmake to include this parameter with a custom value.

Comment: You can add parameters to UIC command line, but it will work for all ui files. `QMAKE_UIC += -params to add`

Comment: Add this to the *.pro file, correct?

Comment: Because ui translations would be big mess

Comment: Yes, add it to the *.pro file. Take a look here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-uic

Comment: ok. seems to work nicely. If you add your comment as an answer i'll accept it so that you can have the credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify QMAKE_UIC property in your .pro file

```
QMAKE_UIC += -params to add
```